# Backup Mysql - JSP

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp

Es la primera vez que intento hacer un backup de una BD `Mysql` desde un `JSP`

Este es mi código (En algún foro lo vi).

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@page import ="java.util.Calendar" %>
<%
try{
    Calendar fecha = Calendar.getInstance();
    String fechaHoy = fecha.get(Calendar.DATE)+"-"+fecha.get(Calendar.MONTH)+"-"+fecha.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    String nombre = "Respaldo_Sistema_"+fechaHoy+".sql";
    int copia_seguridad;

    Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump.exe --opt  --password='' --user=root --databases seapto2 -r C:/"+nombre);

    copia_seguridad = runtimeProcess.waitFor(); 

    if(copia_seguridad==0){ //Devuelve 0 si todo ha salido bien
%>      <script> 
            function respaldoRealizado() {
                alert("El respaldo ha sido creado con exito.\n\nCompruebe la ubicacion del archivo en el disco local \nC:");
                location.href="inicio.jsp"; 
            } 
            respaldoRealizado(); 
        </script> 
<%        
    } else {
%>      <script> 
            function respaldoNoRealizado() {
                alert("El respaldo no se pudo generar");
                location.href="inicio.jsp"; 
            } 
            respaldoNoRealizado(); 
        </script> 
<%  
    }

} catch(Exception e){
    out.println(e);
    } 
%>
```

El problema es que no me genera ningún error, pero tampoco me genera el `backup`...

Alguna idea??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola a todos los que vieron mi publicación;

El error era muy simple ... de principiante :)

En el proceso de creación "rutina" tenia lo siguiente:

```
Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump.exe --opt  --password='' --user=root --databases seapto2 -r C:/"+nombre);
```

Al intentar acceder a la BD la contraseña debía ser `NULL` algo así :

```
password= ;
```

Yo por el contrario tenia:

```
password=''
```

......
Despues de eso debi arreglar el nombre  del archivo, los separadores "-" causan aveces problemas, el resultado funcional seria algo asi:

```
String fechaHoy = fecha.get(Calendar.DATE)+"_"+fecha.get(Calendar.MONTH)+"_"+fecha.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Saludos!!

Answer (score 2):

Experimente el mismo error.

En el proceso de creación rutina (runtimeProcess) tenia lo siguiente:

```
Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump.exe --opt  --password='' --user=root --databases db_taxi -r C:/"+nombre);
```

El error me mostraba al intentar acceder a la base de datos, en caso que la contraseña sea NULL, como es el caso se muestra de esta manera:

```
password=''
```

Pero deberia ser asi

```
password=
```

Y el código quedaría de esta manera:

```
Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\xampp\\mysql\\bin\\mysqldump.exe --opt  --password=  --user=root --databases db_taxi -r C:/"+nombre);
```